# How does this read: Ex P(x)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let P(x) be the statement "x + 1 = 2x" domain is all integers, what is the truth value?

$\exists x P(x)  (E should be backwords...)

I know how to do P(0).  But how exactly do I do this one?  I wouldn't just want a True or False.  Please explain how I can figure this out, and how I should read it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean $\exists$, it is read "there exists," so that $\exists x$ would read "There exists an $x$ so that $P(x)$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(x)$ is not a statement. It is a *predicate*, meaning its truth value depends on $x$. You cannot assign a truth value to a predicate without specifying the input.

$\exists x P(x)$ is a statement. It means "There is at least one particular $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true." This is a true statement, since $P(1)$ is true (i.e. $1 + 1 = 2 \cdot 1$).